# Spread already open files into split view

Tags: buffers, split, multiple-files, tabbed-user-interface

Suppose I open multiple files in `vim` like this:

```
vim a.cc b.cc x.cc
```

`vim` will open all files, but show only one at a time, the rest being accessible using the `:next` command.

After having these files opened, how to spread them into a split view, like if I had used the `-O` flag when opening them? Also, it would be nice to know how can I spread them into tabs too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a bunch of helpful commands for you:

To open every buffer in a horizontal split:

```
:sball
```

To open every buffer in a *vertical* split:

```
:vert sball
```

You can do the same thing with tabs, e.g, to open every buffer into its own tab:

```
:bufdo tab split
```

If you would like more control over how they get split, you can do this individually.

First, list every open buffer with:

```
:ls
```

Then you can choose what to do for each buffer.

To open buffer **N** in a horizontal split:

```
:sb N
```

sb is an abbreviation of `:sbuffer`

To open buffer **N** in a vertical split:

```
:vert sb N
```

To open buffer **N** in a new tab:

```
:tabedit | bN
```

Comment: Don't forget about `:sball`. :)

Comment: From your answer and the comment above, I could derive what I actually wanted: `:vert sball`. Thanks folks.

Comment: @Kira I was actually just about to add that into my answer, but still I'm glad that I could help!

Comment: BTW, I feel `:bufdo tab split` does not quite do what you intend to do. If you open files like `vim a b c`, then run that command, you will end up with 4 open files, `a b c c`. IDK why though, but I tested it here.

Comment: @Kira You're right, I'm not sure what causes that. You could do `:exe "bufdo tab split" | q`, but that seems kinda hacky.

Comment: Shouldn't you advice the OP about the difference between files, buffers, and windows before pointing him to the tiny green [s]balls?